# Intellij Idea 12 Ultimate cannot correctly import pom for Scala project

Tags: scala, maven, intellij-idea

I have a project I've been working with in Idea for weeks with no issues.  I added a new maven dependency and it was not able to find the classes in it, even with maven re-import run, invalidating caches, etc.  So, I started over by re-importing the pom - but now it cannot find ANY of the Scala symbols, even auto-imported Scala symbols.  I have tried this multiple times with the same result.  Here is the pom in question (with some details changed):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.aa</groupId>
    <artifactId>test-project</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <!-- Explicitly declaring the source encoding eliminates the following message: -->
        <!-- [WARNING] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered
            resources, i.e. build is platform dependent! -->
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>

        <compiler.plugin.version>2.3.1</compiler.plugin.version>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- Scala -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
            <version>2.10.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.scalatest</groupId>
            <artifactId>scalatest_2.10.0</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.M5</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Akka -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.typesafe.akka</groupId>
            <artifactId>akka-actor_2.10</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.typesafe.akka</groupId>
            <artifactId>akka-remote_2.10</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.typesafe.akka</groupId>
            <artifactId>akka-kernel_2.10</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.scala-tools</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-scala-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>compile</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>compile</phase>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>test-compile</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>testCompile</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>test-compile</phase>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>process-resources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.scalastyle</groupId>
                <artifactId>scalastyle-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.2.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <verbose>false</verbose>
                    <failOnViolation>true</failOnViolation>
                    <includeTestSourceDirectory>true</includeTestSourceDirectory>
                    <failOnWarning>false</failOnWarning>
                    <sourceDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/scala</sourceDirectory>
                    <testSourceDirectory>${basedir}/src/test/scala</testSourceDirectory>
                    <configLocation>${basedir}/src/main/resources/scalastyle_config.xml</configLocation>
                    <outputFile>${project.basedir}/scalastyle-output.xml</outputFile>
                    <outputEncoding>UTF-8</outputEncoding>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>check</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${compiler.plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${maven.compiler.source}</source>
                    <target>${maven.compiler.target}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

I've been fighting with this for an hour now and am about at my wit's end.  It builds fine from the command-line.  But, again, nothing builds in Idea - it doesn't even see the symbols in scala.predef, etc.

Enabling the Scala facet for the module doesn't make any difference either.

I didn't find any reports of similar issues so perhaps I really am missing something.

Comment: Removing the Scala facet then re-adding it with "Add Framework Support..." got me halfway there.  I was still not able to get it to pick up maven dependencies (nothing special about them at all), so I finally resorted to adding them manually as Idea maven libraries in project structure.  It's now building & running again.  I guess this is why the Scala plugin is well < 1.0

Comment: This sounds like a bug I often experience on Java projects.  My solution is to delete a character from the pom, let intellij process that mistake, then undo.  This seems to force it to realize the dependencies in my project.  See if that works for you.

Comment: No - I tried that too. Tried everything, including re-importing multiple times.  I suspect this is specific to using the Scala plugin.  Adding the dependencies as project libs is the workaround, but will be painful with lots of them.

Comment: I used your pom and I couldn't see any problems. Can you give some information regarding your actual problem? Maybe a scala class with the errors you get.

Comment: Nothing scala was recognized - nothing in the Scala SDK.  Meaning the first error is on an reference to Int.  Nor was any simple from any library recognized (Scala or Java).  So, Idea was just in a completely screwed-up state.  It's obvious an Idea bug - no issues with the pom - and it's highly sporadic.  As I said I got it to work  by re-installing the plugin & resetting its use, but then I did have to add all mvn dependencies as libraries.

Comment: Meant 'symbol' above, not 'simple'!